# iterate on scala list and treating last iteration differently

Tags: scala

I have a list of objects that I am calling `toString` on, and would like to treat the last object differently as follows:

```
o1 = Array(...)
o2 = Array(...) // same length as o1
sb = new StringBuilder()
for (i <- 0 to o1.size() - 1)
  sb.append(o1.get(i).toString() + " & " o2.get(i).toString()) 
  // if not last iteration then append ", "
```

is there a simple way to write this in scala rather than checking value of `i` etc?

Comment: if all items are unique, you can compare `o1.last` to `o1.get(i)`, if they are equal then don't append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jwvh's anwser is good.

just give another pattern-matching version.

```
o1.zip(o2).map{case (item1, item2) => s"$item1 & $item2"}.mkString(", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
o1.zip(o2).map(t => s"${t._1} & ${t._2}").mkString(", ")
```

Zip the arrays together, turn each pair into the desired string, let `mkString()` insert the commas.